# Should return be after a transaction is disposed of?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

I have some code that needs to be inside of a transaction. I've used a using with begintransaction. I of course need to return after I've committed the transaction, but should I return inside the using or outside it?

```
using (var context = MyDBContext)
{
    using (var scope = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var res = myResult;

        scope.Commit();
        return res;
    }
}
```

I'm worried that if the commit fails. The return won't show that if the return happens outside of the using.

Comment: It makes no difference. `using` effectively introduces a `finally` block, so the dispose always happens, regardless of how the block is exited (and a `return` cannot happen "after" the method has exited).

Comment: The _res_ variable is inside the using block. Outside it is undefined

Comment: if the commit fails, the `Commit()` should throw an exception and you'll never hit the `return`; if the `using` fails after the `Commit()`, it should throw before you *actually* return; short version: it doesn't matter, you're fine

Comment: @Steve that's easily solved, of course